# iOS Animating a series of images

Tags: ios, objective-c, animation, nstimer

I have an iOS App that loads a set of images and a duration into an array then I have a timer that displays the images like so:

```
- (void)fireTimer:(NSTimer *)theTimer
{
    self.image = [frames objectAtIndex:currentFrame];
    NSTimeInterval time = [[durations objectAtIndex:currentFrame] floatValue];
    self.timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:time target:self selector:@selector(fireTimer:) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
    currentFrame++;
    if (currentFrame >= [frames count])
    {
        currentFrame = 0;
        [timer invalidate];
    }
}
```

To start the animation I call fireTimer and cycle through the images then when all the images are processed I call [timer invalidate] to stop the animation.  I cannot use startAnimation because I need different durations for each image.

Right know I am NOT doing this on a background thread so the animation is choppy because other processing is happening whilst the image animates.

What is the best way to animate this in the background?  Can I simply put this call to fireTimer in a block?

I know this may not be the best way to animate an image on iOS, but I do not want to do a lot of refactoring on the code right now.

Thanks for any suggestions or examples for a better solution!!!

Comment: Drop the timer completely. It's a very crude animation mechanism that should pretty much never be used. Instead, start by looking at UIImageView and its animation API.

Comment: David, thanks for the suggestion.  I have found other ways of doing the animation, but they require more code changes then what we want to do right now. I completely agree with you that it is crude, but at the time it was written it did suffice.

Comment: A timer is the only way to go because you stated that each frame needs to display for differing amounts of time. You must take care to avoid allocating a whole array of UIImage objects, since that will crash your device after all system memory has been consumed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest you use UIImageView to animate your images : it is made to do this task. If, like you say, some images needs to remains longer then others, then you can just display them many times. Let's say that image2 needs to be displayed twice longer than image1 and image3, just initialize the array `animationImages` on your `UIImageView` like : `@[image1, image2, image2, image3]`.

Comment: LOL, simple, I did not think of that, however, they are not necessarily twice as long, but I suppose I could find a minimum, common value that would suffice.  I will see if any other suggestions come about, if nothing then I will modify my array and try it.  Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Keep in mind that this suggested approach of using animationImages will crash your device when you run out of memory. Use of a timer and parsing each frame before it is loaded is the better approach.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a timer, you could use `performSelector: withObject: afterDelay:`

```
-(void)loopBackground:(int)index
{
    if(index < [self.durations count]{
        self.image = [self.frames objectAtIndex:index];
        [self performSelector:@selector(loopBackground:) withObject:index++ afterDelay:[[self.durations objectAtIndex:index] floatValue]];
    }
}
```